# Is there ability to disable Spell checking for TextBlock in UWP?

Tags: uwp, spell-checking, textblock

I have not found bool answer to this question. Is there any way to disabled Spell checking for TextBlock in UWP for control like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyUrl}" />
```

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/design/input/use-input-scope-to-change-the-touch-keyboard) tell that IsSpellCheckEnabled = false, but VS2017 (15.9.11) does not agree with this article and tells: Error    XLS0413 The property 'IsSpellCheckEnabled' was not found in type 'TextBlock'.

Comment: What is the minimum system version do you target? Maybe increase it and it will suffice.

Comment: Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0; Build 17134)

Comment: Unfortunately for the current moment its the last, but the idea is good. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there ability to disable Spell checking for **TextBlock** in UWP?

`TextBlock` does not have spell check behavior. However, `TextBox` and `RichEditBox` have this feature.

And there is [`IsSpellCheckEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.isspellcheckenabled) property that use to turn on or off this feature within uwp.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" />
```

For more detail please refer [**Guidelines for spell checking**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/text-controls#guidelines-for-spell-checking).